# Change the routing of VPN to a local IP

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, ip, routing

I'm new to the VPN stuff and have a problem with my first setup.

I created a private VPN with ZeroTier for playing old LAN games with my friends. The problem is that the VPN has an IP address range somewhere at 10.147.0.0 to 10.147.255.255, and old software does not recognize it as virtual LAN. So no servers are listed and a connect command or console sometimes doesn't exist.

The goal is to create an internal route in Windows to link an IP of the VPN to my local net.

I need something like 192.168.0.100 --> 10.147.20.62, to let the old software see the local address, and Windows routes it to the VPN. Is this possible?

I tried

```
route add 10.147.20.62 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.100 IF 24
```

and the other way round

```
route add 192.168.0.100 mask 255.255.255.255 10.147.20.62 IF 24
```

but a `ping 192.168.0.100` tells me the host is not reachable.

---

Update

As requested, I describe what I actually want the computers to do.

My desktop PC has got an IP address 192.168.0.2, assigned by my local router to my physical adapter.
The desktop PC also got another IP address 10.147.x.10 assigned by the VPN provider to my virtual adapter.

The same goes for my friend in another city (VPN address 10.147.x.20).

We can see our shares due to the fact, that we are in the same VPN (10.147.x.0). But because the IP address range 10.147.x.0-255 is not a classical LAN range, some software does not recognize that there is a connection.

I want the virtual adapters address of my friend (10.147.x.20) be accessible by a local IP address 192.168.0.100 in my own network.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPixz.png)

I don't know how to call it. Forwarding, masking, routing? But is it possible, what I want my PC to do?

Comment: For old games, creating your own vpn is not always suitable because that only does TCP/IP, whereas old games use IPX transmissions instead. I would suggest to look into hamache, a VPN service designed to play local area network games over the internet.

Comment: Hamachi is not for free anymore.

Comment: what do you mean by "and old software does not recognize it as virtual LAN"? Why do you need "something like 192.168.0.100 --> 10.147.20.62"? What is it suppose to do exactly and why (how is it suppose to help)? PS. I assume ping 10.147.20.62 works?

Comment: @StefanL. From the hamachi website: Hamachi is free for up to 5 computers in your network. If you run Hamachi as a service in unattended mode, you can choose from our subscription packages below.

Answer (score 0):

What you are **actually** doing is routing IP 10.147.20.62 to through the gateway 192.168.0.100 (and the other way around) using the interface ID 21. I'm not sure you understand what "routing" is and your solution is most likely the wrong approach (unless I misunderstood you). If I understood correctly you want want to something like "forward IP x.x.x.1 to IP x.x.x.2". To do this you need to exchange the destination of the IP packet, this is not what routing does.

I would suggest you describe the "actual" problem and it's context in detail maybe adding some screenshots etc. **not just** the (wrong) solution and or what your think the problem is (although the info about your assumed problem might be helpful this most likely is not the actual problem). And if you do write about the solution please add the source for your solution that is often helpful as well.

Or try LPChip solution from the comments.

PS. A possible solution might be NAT or IPtables (whatever the windows equivalent of IPtables is).

PPS. Here are a few pointers for you to get some further knowledge [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/954665/how-to-redirect-route-ip-address-to-another-ip-address), [another forum](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28475524/Redirect-IP-request-to-a-Different-IP.html), [another forum](https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1361510) should be enough to enable you to search yourself.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @StefanL. unfortunately you more or less just described "the same thing" you described before the "update". There not really any new/useful information. If you search for [Private IP-address](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=private+ip+adresses) you'll see that any IP in the 10.147.0.0 range is "as classical" as any IP-address in the 192.168.0.0 range, it's just a different range (just unknown to you). It's very unlikely your game servers is limited to certain IP range, the problem most likely lies s.w. else and the solution as well. Sorry, I'm not able to help you any further at this point.

Comment: @StefanL. If you want to retry, try **not** to describe what you **think** the "source of the problem" is. But the actual "problem", which you only did very briefly ("no servers are listed") definitely add more context. What game server is it, how did you set it up, did you get it to work without vpn, show screenshots etc. ...